# New Android Studio project created without drawable-ldpi,drawable-mdpi etc

Tags: android, android-studio, android-drawable, dpi

When I create a new Android Studio project (version 2.2 - the latest) my project is created without the `drawable-xxxx` folders(xxxx refers to the various dpi).

Now I know I can add them myself but there is a way in the creation of a new project in Android Studio to check/uncheck a box that will build those folders for me?

Answer (score 0):

In new Android Studio, Click on Project Files tab and you will see all the folders, just put items in them and they will be visible.

Here is sample

[image]

**OPTION 2:**

When you copy a image and then go to your drawable and try to paste it shows you a dialog like this

[image]

Comment: Maybe I'm mistaken. My tab is on project. And I don't have an options for project files.

Comment: then God can help you

Comment: OK i found it but I don't have any `src/main` tab in there.

Comment: I will. And in matter of fact I don't have any `drawable` folder in the project files view.

Comment: About the edit. It shows a dialog with only one option. `drawable`.